# Elevated AHK script refuses to receive runtime arguments from PowerShell

Tags: autohotkey

For a long time I have been using this excellent function by SKAN, [RunAsTask() - Auto-elevates script without UAC prompt - AutoHotkey Community](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=4334)

It lets you always run a script as elevated, every single time without being prompted by UAC (You will be prompted once, for every new script).

You simply need to place `RunAsTask()` at the top of the script.

I just discovered, that you cannot pass command line arguments to a script that is going to run as elevated.

I am absolutely gutted, this throws a wrench at so many of my programs and tools.

```
RunAsTask()
MsgBox, % A_args[1]
```

If I have a `.ahk` script consisting of only the above and in a PowerShell terminal invoking:

```
. "C:\Temp\MyScript.ahk" "Hello World"
```

The script never receives this message, the message box is empty.

The only way I can get the script to receive `Hello World` is by uncommenting `runAsTask()` or running PowerShell as Admin.

Neither of which as an option for me, I use the terminal a lot, I cannot imagine doing so as Admin, it's just too dangerous.

I also cannot cannot run scripts as non-elevated as then they won't be able to interact with elevated processes.

I don't even know what is the culprit, is it `RunAsTask`? Is it a general thing to do with UAC? Has anyone come across this issue before?

I would really appreciate any ideas on how to solve this issue or any insight into the cause. Thanks!